# NHibernate 3.2 QueryOver distinct by property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have two classes

```
public class News
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Topic { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
     public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ISet<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

And mappings

```
 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="News" namespace="NewsManagement.Models">
     <class name="News" table="News">
        <id name="Id">
             <generator class="native" />
         </id>
         <property name="Date" not-null="true" />
         <many-to-one name="Category" fetch="join" column="CategoryId" class="Category, NHibernateManyToOne" not-null="true"/>
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>

 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="News" namespace="NewsManagement.Models">
     <class name="Category" table="Categories">
         <id name="Id" column="Id">
             <generator class="native" />
         </id>
         <set name="News" fetch="join" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
             <key column="CategoryId" />
             <one-to-many class="News, NHibernateOneToMany" /> 
         </set>
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

And i want to take paged news, sorted by its category's name.
Here is the query:

```
Session.QueryOver<News>().JoinQueryOver(x => x.Category).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc.Skip(pageNumber*pageSize).Take(pageSize).List<News>();
```

But in result i take many duplicated news in my list. I think it's probably because of joins both enabled in mappings and used in query. So, is there any solution how to do distinct by one property or another way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own IEqualityComparer and add it to your query like this.

```
class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<News>
{
    public bool Equals(News x, News y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(News obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
 Session.QueryOver<News>().JoinQueryOver(x => x.Category).List<News>()
            .Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer())
            .OrderBy(x => x.Category.Name).Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Consider fixing your join so you don't get duplicates adding `.Left` to your join.

```
Session.QueryOver<News>().Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Category)
```

As described in the documentation.

- [NHibernate Reference Documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations)

Comment: but i can't apply `Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer())` nowhere except `List<News>()`. If I'll apply `Distinct` to this it won't be what i need, because it'll delete it from list, as i understand

Comment: So, apply it at the end after `.List<News>()`

Comment: it works, but not in suitable way. For example, one page should contain 5 records, but after distinct on list it has only 2. So I need somehow apply distinct not to list

Comment: Well, you can apply it after `JoinQueryOver`, that would be the most suitable place, I just don't know what type that method returns. If it is `IEnumarable<News>` or `IQueryable<News>`, then you can just use my code. Otherwise, you may have to adapt it, but the idea is there.
Also, please consider upvoting or accepting this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: See my Edit. If you fix your join, you may not need to use Distinct at all.

Comment: it still has duplicates. I tried out different joins (left, inner etc.) but result is the same every time

Comment: You should inspect at which point do you get duplicates. Is it after `QueryOver<News>()` or after `JoinQueryOver(x => x.Category)`

Comment: duplicates appear after `JoinQueryOver(x => x.Category)`

Comment: OK, so what I would do, is call `List<News>()` after `JoinQueryOver`, then call `Distinct` and then Order and Sort them as you need. See my original code.